# Python3 Discord ChatBot respond with no prefix or @

Tags: python, bots, discord, chatbot

Hi so I am making a clever.io chatbot and I want it to respond while people are talking in general chat with our you know like auto reaction non of this

(M) yo
(B) hay

I want it to respond to any type of message that a user says not a @ or prefix or reaction word so please help

What do I do to edit this to have that

```
import discord
import asyncio
import requests
import json

client = discord.Client()
user = '##########################'
key = '###########################'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as '+client.user.name+' (ID:'+client.user.id+') | '+str(len(client.servers))+' servers')
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='chat with me!'))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot and (message.server == None or client.user in message.mentions):
        await client.send_typing(message.channel)
        txt = message.content.replace(message.server.me.mention,'') if message.server else message.content
        r = json.loads(requests.post('https://cleverbot.io/1.0/ask', json={'user':user, 'key':key, 'nick':'lol', 'text':txt}).text)
        if r['status'] == 'success':
            await client.send_message(message.channel, r['response'] )

print('Starting...')
requests.post('https://cleverbot.io/1.0/create', json={'user':user, 'key':key, 'nick':'lol'})
client.run('#########################################')
```

Comment: `on_message` will respond to every message the bot can see.  What is `not message.author.bot` supposed to do?

Comment: i think its so pose to make it so the bot dosn't relay the message back to me
i haven't written this script its a template from frostbot frost.py